# What functionality is available from Drupal.theme()

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I have some complex data in javascript I need to render, mostly as tables.

[This page](https://drupal.org/node/304258#drupal-theme) explains how to add new theme functions, but I just want to create basic vanilla html. [This](https://drupal.org/node/132442#javascript-themeing) apparently is the "official documentation."

I can't for the life of me find a list of the functions/functionality available in Drupal.theme()

I note this [list of functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) available from php - but I'm assuming the javascript version is a subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the JS theme functions defined by core:

**Tabledrag**

- `Drupal.theme.prototype.tableDragChangedMarker`
- `Drupal.theme.prototype.tableDragIndentation`
- `Drupal.theme.prototype.tableDragChangedWarning`

**Vertical Tabs**

- Drupal.theme.prototype.verticalTab

**Overlay Module**

- `Drupal.theme.prototype.overlayContainer`
- `Drupal.theme.prototype.overlayElement`

Many contrib modules also define their own theme functions, it's not possible to list all of those here so your best best is to run a `grep -nr "Drupal.theme.prototype" /path/to/drupal` and see what's available in your own installation.

It's also worth bearing in mind that individual theme functions will only be available in the page if the file that contains them has been included. So if the Overlay module is disabled, for example, the related theme functions won't be available. If the vertical tabs JS hasn't been added that won't be available, and so on.

Comment: thanks Clive - that is a small subset isnt it? I was hoping for a longer list of useful list/table contructs. oh well. Grep tip is very nice too.